# Unable to swipe down screen in an Android apk version

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

So there are 15 boxes on the screen and I am able to insert values for 8 of them on the screen [image]

enter code here

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Threading;


namespace MobileTesting
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
       
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialise()
        {
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
            cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "10.0");
            cap.SetCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\jamesa\\Downloads\\app-debug.apk");
            cap.SetCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
            cap.SetCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
            
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()

        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //Login Page
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[1]")).SendKeys("TestUser");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText[2]")).SendKeys("newpassword");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View[5]/android.widget.Button")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //Dashboard feature
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.widget.Button")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[3]")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[5]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("6");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[5]/android.view.View[4]/android.widget.Button")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[6]/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.Button")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[3]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[4]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[5]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[6]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            **// scroll down to access the other options
            //AndroidElement list = (AndroidElement)driver.FindElement(By.Id("trait8"));
            //list.Click();
            strong textdriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[8]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            //((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
            //Thread.Sleep(3000); 
            //element.SendKeys("5");**

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[9]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[10]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[11]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[12]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[13]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[14]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[7]/android.view.View[15]/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("5");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
}}
```

Note:
I have high lighted in bold at the place where I am stuck at and it says "scroll down to view other options" in comments

It will be really helpful to let me know your answers in detail as I am new to codes :-)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use touchActions in appium to scroll like this :

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
action.scroll(element, 10, 100);
action.perform();
```

or using giving reference to 2 elements as :

```
TouchAction().press(el0).moveTo(el1).release();
```

For your reference :
https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

Comment: we are getting this error when used the first method above : -System.ArgumentException: The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen. (Parameter 'driver')

Comment: Use can wrap your driver to AndroidDriver and can use that driver for touchaction.